# How do I use external auth via MVC API from iOS?

Tags: ios, api, model-view-controller, oauth

Background: I'm trying to use social oath providers to sign up and sign in on an iOS app. I believe MVC's API is the right way of doing this, but I have a few holes.

The MVC API has a GET /Account/ExternalLogin API call that returns valid external login providers, (often social) login options.

How should I use this from iOS?

Additional parts to this question:

- I'm not familiar with the x-auth-token header but I think I'll need to use this in combination with the JSON payload itself. How do I use this?
- Buried in the payload is a double encoded URL that I can use with something like GTM oAuth. Is this something I need to decode twice before I use it?
- GTM oAuth library looks like a candidate library to use to help out.
- Is ExternalLogins the right place to start? If I try and login from the app then the app needs to know client secrets and the like. Shouldn't these be managed safely in the API?

I'm happy to refine this question if it's not up to scratch before you reject it.

Thanks!